# (R, xtable package) sanitize.text.function is not working

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I want to include a data table from R in a LaTeX file. I am using `xtable`and the problem is that the function `sanitize.text.function` is not working properly. MWE:

```
> a <- matrix(c("name & surname", 12345), ncol = 2)
     [,1]             [,2]   
[1,] "name & surname" "12345"


 > print.xtable(xtable(a), type = "latex", sanitize.text.function = function(x){x}, file = "../R_out/prova.tex")

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rll}
  \hline
 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  \hline
1 & name & surname & 12345 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see there is a `&` in excess.

The only other similar question that I could find on stackoverflow concerned the location of the option `sanitize.text.function`, but in my case it should be correctly placed. Can you see the problem here?

Comment: Try `print.xtable(xtable(a), type = "latex")`, i.e. without passing your own custom `sanitize.text.function`. You are currently telling `xtable` that you do not want the `&` to be escaped, which is what causes the problem.

Comment: @coffeinjunky you are perfectly right. I misinterpreted the `sanitize.text.function` function, thanks.